# Perdendo a tradução com ngx-translate ao dar o build com --prod

Tags: ionic3, i18n, angular-cli

```
    // translate
    import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization';
    import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core'; 
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader'; 

    export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) { 
      return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json'); 
    } 

    TranslateModule.forRoot({ 
      loader: { 
        provide: TranslateLoader, 
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader, 
        deps: [HttpClient] 
      } 
    }),
```

Estou trabalhando em um projeto feito em Ionic 3.

Quando eu dou um `ionic cordova run android --livereload` a tradução funciona normalmente.

Porém quando uso `ionic cordova run android --prod` ou `ionic cordova build android --prod` a tradução não funciona mais, alguém ja passou por isso e poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abaixo está uma imagem de como foi feito a estrutura de pasta para a tradução.

[image: Estrutura feita para tradução]

Como está descrito nos imports da questão, eu utilizo o `Globalization` para pegar o idioma de preferência do aparelho e em um outro arquivo eu utilizo o  `TranslateService`

```
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";

const lang = TranslateService.getBrowserCultureLang()
```

A função `getBrowserCultureLang` me da a preferência do browser...

Ambos me dão a extensão com a cultura:

> lang = 'pt-BR'

ou

> lang = 'en-US'

O que estava acontecendo é que eu passava o `lang` na função `TranslateService.setDefaultLang(lang);` do jeito que ele me era entregue.

É **necessário** passa o `lang` com o conteúdo todo em minúsculo.

ex: `TranslateService.setDefaultLang(lang.toLowerCase())`

> lang = 'pt-br'

ou

> lang = 'en-us'